# Selenium won't locate an element on what seems like a pop-up

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, popup, element

For this project, I am trying to search for credit unions in a certain area. When I search for the address and get the list of credit unions in that area, selenium won't locate the elements to print them. I have tried these two methods but neither of them will work. Is there something I'm missing? I've read about Action Chains but I'm not too sure how they work or if they would apply to this. Thank you!

```
from selenium import webdriver

address = 'anything'

#Go to link to get all credit unions in the area

driver.get('https://mapping.ncua.gov/')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input[1]').send_keys(address)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input[2]').click()

#    Method #1

#Print the name of the credit unions by using a loop and finding the class name

names = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('name')

    for name in names:
        print(name.text)

#   Method #2

#Print the name of the credit unions by using a loop and finding the xpath

for y in range(1, 10):

    y = str(y)

    name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr['+y+']/td[1]/a/span[1]').text
    print(name)
```

Comment: Can you share the output of both the methods that you've tried ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... I just needed to wait 2 seconds for the page to load. Both methods of finding the element now work as they should.